# How can I select an element inside a div with a specific attribute in JQUERY?

Tags: jquery

I need to select a label inside a div with a specific attribute and trigger a click.
I want to trigger a click only when data-original-title has a specific value (in this case white)

```
<div id="productoptioncolor" class="form-group required">
 <label class="control-label">Color </label>
 <div id="input-option3490">
  <div data-toggle="tooltip" class="colorbx" title="" data-original-title="White">
   <label rel="9333" data-value="2" id="colorboxbtnx9333" class="colorboxbtn">
    <input style="opacity:0" type="radio" name="option[3490]" value="9333">
   </label>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I am trying with this and it is not working

```
$("#productoptioncolor div div[data-original-title='White'] label").trigger('click');
```

When I use

```
$("#productoptioncolor div div:first-child label").trigger('click');
```

It works but it is not what I need

Any thoughts?

Comment: It's working fine for me, are you sure it is not working?

Comment: As @Terry says, that selector does seem to be successfully matching the DOM node you want.  Can you clarify what exactly is not working as you expect?  (Possibly it's something to do with the click event which you haven't shown, instead of the selector?)

Comment: That code works for me. I suspect this may be a timing issue - your code is running before bootstrap (or whatever) tooltip code is running. This means that the attribute `data-original-title` does not exist when your javascript runs. As a proof-of-concept, wrap your javascript in a `setTimeout` for 500 milliseconds - does it work now? If so, you need to reorganise your code so that your stuff runs AFTER the tooltip stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Click event works fine with the second example (in this case they should select the same element)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this?

```
$("[data-original-title='White'] label").trigger('click');
```